# Inno Setup ParseVersion is not callable from [Code]

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

The macros `ParseVersion` and `RemoveBackslash`, for example, are both declared in `ISPPBuiltins.iss`.  If I attempt to call both from within [Code]:

```pascal
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
    Major, Minor, Rev, Build: Integer;
begin
    RemoveBackslash('123\');
    ParseVersion('12345', Major, Minor, Rev, Build);
end;
```

`RemoveBackslash` compiles fine, but adding `ParseVersion` causes a compiler error:

> Unknown identifier 'ParseVersion'"

When part of another macro declaration, `ParseVersion` seems to compile fine, just not from `[Code]`.  Should I be able call it like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Andrew wrote already, the `ParseVersion` (or actually since [Inno Setup 6.1](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6.1-whatsnew.htm#6.1.0), the [`GetVersionComponents`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=getversioncomponents)) is a preprocessor function. So it has to be called using preprocessor directives and its results stored into preprocessor variables.

```
#define Major
#define Minor
#define Rev
#define Build
#expr GetVersionComponents("C:\path\MyProg.exe", Major, Minor, Rev, Build)
```

If you need to use the variables in the Pascal Script `Code`, you again need to use preprocessor syntax. For example:

```pascal
[Code]

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  MsgBox('Version is: {#Major}.{#Minor}.{#Rev}.{#Build}.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  Result := True;
end;
```

---

The above is true, if you really want to extract the version numbers on the compile-time. If you actually want to do it in the `Code` section, i.e. on the install-time, you have to use [Pascal Script support function `GetVersionComponents`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getversioncomponents) (yes, the same name, but a different language):

```pascal
[Code]

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
  Major, Minor, Rev, Build: Word;
  Msg: string;
begin
  GetVersionComponents('C:\path\MyProg.exe', Major, Minor, Rev, Build);
  Msg := Format('Version is: %d.%d.%d.%d', [Major, Minor, Rev, Build]);
  MsgBox(Msg, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  Result := True;
end;
```

The Pascal Script function `GetVersionComponents` is available since [Inno Setup 6.1](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6.1-whatsnew.htm#6.1.0) only.

---

The `RemoveBackslash` works in both contexts, as there's both [Pascal Script `RemoveBackslash`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_removebackslash) and [Preprocessor `RemoveBackslash`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=removebackslash).

Answer (score 1):

In the [Change Log](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6.1-whatsnew.htm) (for 6.1.x) it mentioned:

> Support function `GetFileVersion` and `ParseVersion` have been renamed to `GetVersionNumbersString` and `GetVersionComponents` respectively. The old names are still supported, but it is recommended to update your scripts to the new names and the compiler will issue a warning if you don't.

So be wary of that when you upgrade. But as you rightly say, these are **Inno Setup Preprocessor (ISPP)** functions. With respects to the **Pascal Script** section there is nothing listed in the [Support Function Reference](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptfunctions.htm).

Someone else might be able to shed more insight about this, or offer a workaround, but you might have to request the feature in the Info Setup [forum](https://groups.google.com/g/innosetup).